# How update *ngFor on updating array using observable and how to initialize observable on website load?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-observable, angular-lifecycle-hooks, angular-ngfor

I have two components "cart" and "home". Here "home" component is displaying list of products and it is the first page of website. I want to update cart when someone add product to the cart using "cart" button. For that I have create a service using observable to send message from "home" to "cart" component.

Problems I'm facing:
1. *ngFor is not updating when updating the array using observable.
2. As I'm initializing observable on ngOnInit() cart array is only updates when I visit cart component at least once.

**home.component.ts**

```
sendToCart(id:string) {
this.addtocart.sendId(id);
}
```

**cart.service.ts**

```
private productIdSource = new Subject<string>();
productId$ = this.productIdSource.asObservable(); 

constructor() { }

sendId(id:string) {
this.productIdSource.next(id);
}
```

**cart.component.ts**

```
itemList:any = ["hello"];

constructor(private addtocart: CartService) {
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.addtocart.productId$.subscribe(
    msg => {
      console.log(msg);
      this.itemList.push(msg);
      console.log(this.itemList);
    }
  )
}
```

**cart.component.html**

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let item of itemList">
    {{item}}
</li>
</ul>
```

I tried "ChangeDetectorRef", markForCheck() and detectChanges() but none of those worked.

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz

Answer (score 0):

Use **BehaviorSubject**:

```
private productIdSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>();
productId$ = this.productIdSource.asObservable(); 

constructor() { }

sendId(id:string) {
   this.productIdSource.next(id);
}
```

Comment: BehaviorSubject kinda works but it only works for adding one item.

Comment: You will adding one item at a time to the cart right?

Comment: From productlist user can add multiple items clicking "+cart" button but quantity is one.

Comment: Ok.. can you share it in stackbiltz

Answer (score 0):

Try overwriting `itemList` instead of mutating:

```
this.addtocart.productId$.subscribe(
    msg => {
      this.itemList = [...this.itemList, msg]; // instead of this.itemList.push(msg);
    }
  )
```

Comment: Array is updating as usual  but not the *ngFor. And that is also when I visit the cart component at least once.